# Prove that $R_1 \times R_2$ is a regular language for $R_1, R_2$ regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Let A and B be two sets. The cross products of A and B are defined as : AxB={(a,b): a belongs to A and b belongs to B }. Assume R1 and R2 are regular languages over an input alphabet Σ={a,b}. Prove R1xR2 is a regular language

Comment: It's not very clear what your question means: a language is a set of strings of symbols. The set-theoretic product of two strings of symbols is not a string of symbols.

Comment: I'm sorry this was exactly how the question was printed. I'm not in a position to change anything because I didn't make much out of the question

Comment: Where did the question come from? You were quite right not to make anything of it, because as it stands it doesn't make sense.

Comment: In that case, why are there 2 well received answers? Oo

Comment: One of those answers makes an intelligent guess at how to fix the question by modifying what it says about the input alphabet. The other is incoherent and there has been no reply to my last comment about it. Sadly, MSE votes are no guarantee of correctness.

Comment: @rob-arthan There is a rigorous fix to this question, but it relies on the notion of a [recognizable set of a monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognizable_set). Mezei's theorem states that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two monoids, then the recognizable subsets of $M_1 \times M_2$ are exactly the finite unions of products of the form $R_1 \times R_2$, where, for $i =1$ or $2$, $R_i$ is a recognizable subset of $M_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A = R_{1}$ and $B = R_{2}$. Let $M(A)$ and $M(B)$ be the finite state machines accepting $A$ and $B$ respectively. Define $M(A \times B)$ to be the machine with states $Q_{A} \times Q_{B}$, transition function $\delta_{A} \times \delta_{B}$ and final states $F_{A} \times F_{B}$. Argue that this machine captures $A \times B$ exactly.

Without loss of generality, suppose each final state has an $\epsilon$ transition looping to itself. So $\delta_{i}(f, \epsilon) = f$ for every $f \in F_{i}$. This accounts for differences in string lengths.

Now suppose $(a, b) \in A \times B$. This implies $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ and $A, B$ are regular, there is a sequence of transitions $(\delta_{A}(q_{x_{i}}, a_{i}))_{i=1}^{n}$ with each $q_{x_{i}} \in Q_{A}$ and $(\delta_{B}(q_{y_{i}}, b_{i}))_{i=1}^{n}$ with each $q_{y_{i}} \in Q_{B}$ such that $M(A)$ terminates in an accepting halt state and $M(B)$ terminates in an accepting halt state. By construction of $M(A \times B)$, we take $(\delta_{A \times B}( (q_{x_{i}}, q_{y_{i}}), (a_{i}, b_{i}))_{i=1}^{n}$, which terminates in a state in $F_{A} \times F_{B}$ by construction.

The converse takes a sequence of product states and then breaks them up. It's just working backwards.

Comment: i was looking for a more detailed explanation and proof. This question was asked for 15 marks in my examination. Argue that this captures AxB exactly. HOW?

Comment: I don't think the original question is very well posed, but I can't make sense of your answer: a run of your $M(A\times B)$ amounts to a run of $M(A)$ in lockstep with a run of $M(B)$. So howdo you recognise $(a, b)$ if $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ don't have the same length?

Comment: Editing my answer now. But we can add $\epsilon$ transition on the final states for both machines to account for this. This does not affect the language accepted by either machine, so this assumption is WLOG.

Comment: Edited to expand. Should be good to go now.

Comment: Yes it's more lucid. The part where you prove that the machine recognizes the language and has a final halt state, is it alright to say in a formal proof that every Regular Language is accepted by a FSA. Like straight ahead?

Comment: Kleene's Theorem says that a language is regular if and only if it is accepted by a FSM. So yes, it is okay to use this characterization.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant to say. Thanks for the name of the theorem. I had no idea it was called this

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are strings of symbols, $(a, b)$ is not. So it's unclear what question your are trying to answer: what are the inputs to your machine supposed to be?

Comment: The alphabet would be $\Sigma \times \Sigma$.

Comment: But a string of symbols drawn from the alphabet $(\Sigma \times \Sigma)$ is not a pair of strings drawn from $\Sigma$.

Comment: The product language has the alphabet $\Sigma \times \Sigma$. Each individual language has the alphabet $\Sigma$. I'm not sure where the miscommunication or confusion lies.

Comment: So if $\Sigma$ comprises the letters of the alphabet, $A = \{\mbox{"apple"}\}$ (one string of 5 letters) and $B = \{\mbox{"pear"}\}$ (one string of four letters), which strings of pairs of letters does your $M(A \times B)$ recognise?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if you define disjoint alphabets for $R_1$ and $R_2$, then, given regular expressions for the languages $R_1$ and $R_2$, all you need to do is concatenate the two regular expressions for $R_1$ and $R_2$ (using their different alphabets) and then, because they use different alphabets, you can tell for each string in this bizarre regular expression, which part of the string belongs to $R_1$ and which part belongs to $R_2$. It's fairly easy to see this is equivalent to recognizing $R_1 \times R_2$.

Comment: That works with a generous interpretation of the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Agreed, sometimes I just "intuit" what is meant because not everyone is good at formulating concrete well-defined questions with a level of rigor that formal mathematics often expects. But in this case I believe I know what was meant, and that (provided one knows regular languages are exactly what are expressible as regular expressions) I think this gives a somewhat good answer.